# One click download component for joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I am working on one joomla(2.5.1) site and i need one module for one click download option in front end.

Let me clear more.

- Admin should be able to upload zip folder from administrator.(There are some files in this zip folder)
- User will be able to download that zip folder in front site.

I googled a lot for similar components but i didnt find anything related to this one.

Advise me what would better way for my requirement.

All feedback are welcome.

Comment: Maybe: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/5551 or http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/2849

Comment: @Shaz , its really useful to me , many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some links:

[Phoca Download](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/5551)

[JDownloads](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/2849)

[Downloads category in JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads)

Comment: Thanks , its exactly what i was looking for, i just couldn't find right keyword , anyway thanks for your help.